Ceph High Latency
I am seeking assistance with a challenging issue related to Ceph that has significantly impacted the company I work for.
Our company has been operating a cluster with three nodes hosted in a data center for over 10 years. This production environment runs on Proxmox (version 6.3.2) and Ceph (version 14.2.15). From a performance perspective, our applications function adequately.
To address new business requirements, such as the need for additional resources for virtual machines (VMs) and to support the company’s growth, we deployed a new cluster in the same data center. The new cluster also consists of three nodes but is considerably more robust, featuring increased memory, processing power, and a larger Ceph storage capacity.
The goal of this new environment is to migrate VMs from the old cluster to the new one, ensuring it can handle the growing demands of our applications. This new setup operates on more recent versions of Proxmox (8.2.2) and Ceph (18.2.2), which differ significantly from the versions in the old environment.
The Problem
During the gradual migration of VMs to the new cluster, we encountered severe performance issues in our applications—issues that did not occur in the old environment. These performance problems rendered it impractical to keep the VMs in the new cluster.
An analysis of Ceph latency in the new environment revealed extremely high and inconsistent latency, as shown in the screenshot below:
<<Ceph latency screenshot - new environment>>
image new environment
To mitigate operational difficulties, we reverted all VMs back to the old environment. This resolved the performance issues, ensuring our applications functioned as expected without disrupting end-users. After this rollback, Ceph latency in the old cluster returned to its stable and low levels:
<<Ceph latency screenshot - old environment>>

With the new cluster now available for testing, we need to determine the root cause of the high Ceph latency, which we suspect is the primary contributor to the poor application performance.
Cluster Specifications
Old Cluster
Controller Model and Firmware:
pm1: Smart Array P420i Controller, Firmware Version 8.32
pm2: Smart Array P420i Controller, Firmware Version 8.32
pm3: Smart Array P420i Controller, Firmware Version 8.32

Disks:
pm1: KINGSTON SSD SCEKJ2.3 (1920 GB) x2, SCEKJ2.7 (960 GB) x2
pm2: KINGSTON SSD SCEKJ2.7 (1920 GB) x2
pm3: KINGSTON SSD SCEKJ2.7 (1920 GB) x2

New Cluster
Controller Model and Firmware:
pmx1: Smart Array P440ar Controller, Firmware Version 7.20
pmx2: Smart Array P440ar Controller, Firmware Version 6.88
pmx3: Smart Array P440ar Controller, Firmware Version 6.88

Disks:
pmx1: KINGSTON SSD SCEKH3.6 (3840 GB) x4
pmx2: KINGSTON SSD SCEKH3.6 (3840 GB) x2
pmx3: KINGSTON SSD SCEKJ2.8 (3840 GB), SCEKJ2.7 (3840 GB)

Tests Performed in the New Environment

Deleted the Ceph OSD on Node 1. Ceph took over 28 hours to synchronize. Recreated the OSD on Node 1.
Deleted the Ceph OSD on Node 2. Ceph also took over 28 hours to synchronize. Recreated the OSD on Node 2.
Moved three VMs to the local backup disk of pmx1.
Destroyed the Ceph cluster.
Created local storage on each server using the virtual disk (RAID 0) previously used by Ceph.
Migrated VMs to the new environment and conducted a stress test to check for disk-related issues.

Questions and Requests for Input

Are there any additional tests you would recommend to better understand the performance issues in the new environment?

Have you experienced similar problems with Ceph when transitioning to a more powerful cluster?

Could this be caused by a Ceph configuration issue?

The Ceph storage in the new cluster is larger, but the network interface is limited to 1Gbps. Could this be a bottleneck? Would upgrading to a 10Gbps network interface be necessary for larger Ceph storage?

Could these issues stem from incompatibilities or changes in the newer versions of Proxmox or Ceph?

Is there a possibility of hardware problems? Note that hardware tests in the new environment have not revealed any issues.

Given the differences in SSD models, controller types, and firmware versions between the old and new environments, could these factors be contributing to the performance and latency issues we’re experiencing with Ceph?



one of the OSDs in the new environment is currently OUT. What's the cluster status? rebalance tasks will impact performance.

proxmox with such a usecase is usually under support of the vendor and as such the vendor offering some tickets including the support on a Flatrate. and that's why I ask why do you not opened a ticket on the vendor?

What's the network in the old cluster? 10Gbps is the absolute minimum I would recommend for a Ceph cluster. And having only three OSDs is not robust at all.

@GeraldSchneider Sorry, that screenshot was taken during our disk testing, which is why one of them was in the OUT state. I’ve updated the post with a more recent image.

@eblock 1Gbps as well, which is why we thought it wouldn’t have a negative impact to continue with the same 1Gbps network. However, we plan to upgrade to 10Gbps.

If the VMs were built on the Nautilus cluster, you didn't have as much replication traffic as you do now when you try to move an entire image at once. That's just an idea, not necessarily true. Is the link saturated? Have you monitored with iftop or similar tools?
